# Replace Values in a String in an Output File with a String from a Source File

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I need to replace the values, specifically the values between the equals sign '`=`' and the colon '`:`' in an existing file called `zoo.cfg`, at the bottom of this file i.e.,

```
...
Server.1=10.42.227.70:2891:3881
Server.2=10.42.229.63:2891:3881
Server.3=10.42.234.18:2891:3881
...
```

With values from a hosts file (i.e., the source file) i.e.,

```
10.42.227.66    zoo1
10.42.229.119   zoo2
10.42.234.21    zoo3
```

Can someone provide guidance on how I can do this?

Additionally, Server.1 in the zoo.cfg file is equal to zoo1, Server.2 is = to zoo2, and Server.3 is equal to zoo3.

To add to the question, in the hosts file, there are multiple entries for other hosts (i.e., hosts other than zoo1, zoo2 and zoo3).  The hosts file contents is as follows:

```
10.42.224.153 dev.nifi1.datacond.dfc
10.42.229.87 dev.nifi2.datacond.dfc
10.42.236.46 dev.nifi3.datacond.dfc
10.42.231.56 zoo1
10.42.224.225 zoo2
10.42.239.41 zoo3
10.42.233.198 controlnode
10.42.231.56 node-master
10.42.230.71 node1
10.42.237.120 node2
```

Is there a way to modify the awk script such that only the zoo host rows are processed i.e., all of the other host entries are ignored?

Comment: Server.1 in the target file is = to zoo1, Server.2 in the target file is = zoo2, and Server.3 is = zoo3.

Comment: Don't add clarifications to your question to the comments. Please [edit] your question and add all the relevant details there. Please add the expect output to your question, ie how the file should look like after the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    map[$2] = $1
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    tgt = FILENAME
    sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",tgt)
}
{
    key = $1
    sub(/=.*/,"",key)
    sub(/.*\./,"",key)
    key = tgt key
}
key in map {
    sub(/=[^:]+/,"=" map[key])
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk hosts zoo.cfg
...
Server.1=10.42.231.56:2891:3881
Server.2=10.42.224.225:2891:3881
Server.3=10.42.239.41:2891:3881
...
```

The above assumes the first field from `host` won't contain any `&`s and none of your fields contain spaces, as shown in your example.

The above was run on these input files:

```
$ head -50 hosts zoo.cfg
==> hosts <==
10.42.224.153 dev.nifi1.datacond.dfc
10.42.229.87 dev.nifi2.datacond.dfc
10.42.236.46 dev.nifi3.datacond.dfc
10.42.231.56 zoo1
10.42.224.225 zoo2
10.42.239.41 zoo3
10.42.233.198 controlnode
10.42.231.56 node-master
10.42.230.71 node1
10.42.237.120 node2

==> zoo.cfg <==
...
Server.1=10.42.227.70:2891:3881
Server.2=10.42.229.63:2891:3881
Server.3=10.42.234.18:2891:3881
...
```

Comment: Hello Ed, thank you for your response!  When I run tst.awk i.e., $awk -f tst.awk hosts zoo.cfg,  the values from the hosts file which contain the following values:  i.e., 10.42.231.57 zoo1, 10.42.224.226 zoo2, 10.42.239.42 zoo3, do not replace the values in the zoo.cfg file.  My goal is to have the IPs from the hosts file for zoo1, zoo2, and zoo3 replace the values contained in the zoo.cfg file. So, the outcome would be:  ... Server.1=10.42.227.66:2891:3381, Server.2=10.42.229.119:2891:3881, Server.3=10.42.234.21:2891:3881.

Comment: We can't see format in a comment. As you can see in my answer, it produces the output you say you want from the input you provided. If that's not what you're experiencing then either you copy/pasted it wrong or your input files don't look like the example in your question. Check for DOS line endings in your input (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: thanks Ed.  I determined the issue.  If the hosts file has other host entries, in addition to the zoo hosts entries e.g., zoo1, zoo2, zoo3, then the awk script does not work.  The script works beautifully when there are only the 3 entries for the zoo nodes.

Comment: All we have to go on when trying to help you is the sample input/output you provide in your question. If the example you provided doesn't adequately represent your needs then edit your question to fix it so it does.

Comment: Ok.  Certainly understand. Will update the question.  I certainly appreciate your guidance/help Ed.

Comment: You added another block of input but not the expected output given that input. Please keep it simple for us - one block of sample input and 1 block of the expected output given that input.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think it probably produces the output you want now.

Comment: Will do Ed. I’ll be sure to provide sample input with corresponding expected output going forward. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks so much Ed!  It worked perfectly.  Thanks also for your  guidance and help!