# Replace String Values in Target File with String Values from Source File

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I need to replace the IP values from a hosts file (the hosts file in this case is the source file), with values in a target file.
...
The host file contents are:

```
10.42.229.1   zoo1
10.42.229.7   zoo2
10.42.237.6   zoo3
```

The existing target file has a keyword "Connect String" that can be used as an anchor.  The structure of the target file is:

```
<property name="Connect String">10.42.229.5:2181,10.42.227.225:2181, 
    10.42.237.6:2181</property>
```

I need to replace the values in the target file with the values from the hosts file.

The order of the values in the target file are:  zoo1, zoo2, and zoo3.

So, the outcome should be:

```
<property name="Connect String">10.42.229.1:2181,10.42.229.7:2181, 
    10.42.237.6:2181</property>
```

Can someone provide guidance on how I can do this?

Comment: I edited your post to make a slight improvement to the formatting, but made a right bollocks of some of the details.  Can you please check that I have maintained the correct intent of your question?

Comment: Thanks Jim.  I read through the question and it looks good.  Thanks for editing the formatting!

Comment: Please stop posting essentially the same question multiple times - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/752295/133219, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/752303/133219, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/752309/133219. Try to apply what you learn from the answer to your first question to any other similar problems before then posting a new question if necessary.