# Need to Replace Values in Output (Target) File with Values from Source File

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I need to replace the values in a target file
with values from a hosts file (the source file), specifically the corresponding IP addresses for hosts zoo1, zoo2 and zoo3.

The hosts file structure is:

```
10.42.229.1    zoo1
10.42.227.228  zoo2
10.42.237.5    zoo3
```

The target file has an anchor called "~nifi.zookeeper.connect.string~".

The structure of the target file is:

```
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=10.42.229.2:2181, 10.42.227.227:2181,10.42.237.9:2181.
```

Can someone provide guidance on how I can replace the values from the hosts file with the corresponding values in the target file.

The outcome would be:

```
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=10.42.229.1:2181,10.42.227.228:2181,10.42.237.5:2181.
```

Comment: Please stop posting essentially the same question multiple times - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/752295/133219, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/752303/133219, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/752309/133219. Try to apply what you learn from the answer to your first question to any other similar problems before then posting a new question if necessary.

Comment: My apologies Ed and thank you for your previous answer.  The questions were slightly different and I certainly need to get smarter on awk.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: No problem, just learn from that answer (and any others you get), try to solve the next slightly different problem on your own by building on that but if you can't fully solve that new problem THEN ask a new question that includes your attempt to solve that problem so we can best help you.

Comment: Thanks Ed.  Will do.